# How can I create an expanded toolbar with background image and a centered thumbnail?

Tags: android

I'm willing to create a custom toolbar for the main menu of an app I'm working on, like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJdjn.png.

It contains a background image and another centered image as thumbnail. It does not collapse and stays static until an item is selected inside one of the tabs.

I'm using Android Studio in the developing process, which can be a little rough to deal with layout, but I believe there's a solution that uses the material design features, but I couldn't find anything about that (besides the toolbar with a background image).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a very complex layout. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the Toolbar widget to your needs. Use something like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Toolbar Title"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" >

    //...your code here

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And then add this toolbar to the top of your UI.

Comment: Hey, thanks for chunk of code! I didn't know it was possible to just customize a toolbar like this. I tried to implement your solution but I couldn't figure out how to add the toolbar to the top of my UI. It looks like the toolbar declared in the themes overrides yours. I need to study the app's themes further to provide a better feedback.

Comment: You don't need to worry too much about themes for this. Don't use ActionBar at all. You can just have a LinearLayout with orientation=vertical, and have the Toolbar as the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you used, it looks like they are using a [`CollapsingToolbarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html) with the collapsing effect turned off. The layout may look something like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/header_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/height_header"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/square_image"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/size_square_image"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_square_image"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's really complete and it looks like it fits in exactly in what I need! I just had some problems with the themes declared in your code – the themes used in our app are a little bit messy and I need to study them further in order to apply your code. When I do I'll provide a better feedback. Thanks again!

Comment: @MaurícioFontana Ah, `AppTheme.AppBarOverlay` and `AppTheme.PopupOverlay` are usually automatically generated by Android Studio when you generate a new `Activity`. If you never did that, or have deleted those themes since, they will not be available. You can just use `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar` and `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light` instead (they are provided by the support library).